# What is the edge length of a cube of volume $160 \text{cm}^3$?

Tags: geometry

> The volume of cube is $160 \text{cm}^3$.  Find the length, in cm, of each edge of the cube. Give the answer correct to three significant figures.

I try to make this question but I don't know how to make this question.  Please explain how to make this question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be length of each of 12 equal edges of the cube then its volume is $$=a^3$$ $$\implies a^3=160$$ $$\implies \color{blue}{a=\sqrt[1/3]{160}\approx 5.43\ cm}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The volume of a cube is given as $x^3$, where $x$ is the length of one of the edges. (Recall that in a cube, all three edges have equal length.)

Hence, you must determine the $x$ such that $160\,\text{cm}^3 = x^3$.